# Kmeans in Matlab, replicates and start

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am calculating kmeans centers for 100 iterations. I have set the initial centroid and replicate equal to 1. In the following steps, I am trying to pass the new centroid:

```
[idx,ctrs1,sumd,D] = kmeans(data,3,'Replicates',1,'start',cen1);
[idx,ctrs2,sumd,D] = kmeans(data,3,'Replicates',1,'start',ctrs1);
...
```

But my centroid is not changing at all, even from the first iteration. Is there a problem in my code?

Comment: Are you sure you understood what `Replicates` is meant for (it's not needed here); instead you probably meant to use `'MaxIter',1`.

Comment: Realized just now. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MaxIter` property instead of the `replicate`.